# Weyl Character Formula to find $M_\lambda(\mu)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

In Introductory Lie algebra book by Humphreys, he has used Weyl Character Formula to find the dimension of $V(\lambda)$ in the examples followed by the proof of this formula. But how to find the dimensions of the weight spaces $M_\lambda(\mu)$ using the Weyl character formula?

There are other formulas to find the dimension of the weight spaces, but I want to do it using the Weyl Character Formula.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose one approach would be to take the character of the $G$-rep you obtain via the WCF and restrict it to your maximal torus $T$. You could take the inner product of this restricted character with that of $\mathbb{C}_{\mu}$.

Comment: In other words, take the inner product with $\mu$.

Comment: @PeterCrooks Can you explain your previous command little bit more ? what is the inner product here? inner product in $H^*$? if it is so, how does it giving the value of $M_\lambda(\mu)$? thanks.

Comment: I am talking about the inner product of characters of $T$. The irreducible representations of $T$ are indexed by the weights of $T$, and their characters form an orthonormal basis of the representation ring of $T$. So, if you take the inner product of $\chi_{M(\lambda)}$ with $\mu=\chi_{\mathbb{C}_{\mu}}$, you will obtain the dimension of $M(\lambda)_{\mu}$.

Comment: The inner product comes from integrating over a compact real form of $T$.

Comment: @PeterCrooks can you suggest me some reference please?

Comment: If a maximal torus $T$ is of rank $n$, then the WCF explicitly gives the character as a quotient of two Laurent polynomials in $n$ variables defined on $T$; so just expand the quotient into a Laurent polynomial in those $n$ variables; this quotient necessarily has finitely many terms. The exponents of these terms correspond to the weights of the representation, so to find the dimension of a particular weight space $\mu = (\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)$ you just have to pick off the coefficient of the $x_1^{\mu_1}\ldots x_n^{\mu_n}$ in this expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little bit confused with Humphreys notations, correct me if I am proving the wrong thing

Let $M(\lambda)$ be the Verma modulus, $L(\lambda)$ -- irreducible factor. I am not shifting by $\rho$.

Then $ch(M(\lambda))=e^\lambda\sum_{\nu \in Q_+}p(\nu)e^{-\nu}$. Weil formula can be rewritten as $ch(L(\lambda))=\sum_{w \in W}\varepsilon(w)ch(M(w(\lambda+\rho)-\rho))$. Thus if $p$ is Kostant partition function you get $\dim L(\lambda)_\mu=\sum_{w \in W}\varepsilon(w) p(w(\lambda+\rho)-\rho-\mu)$. I don't know how to derive more useful formulas a la Freudenthal formula directly.